# Android: how to detect WiFi is fully connected?

Tags: java, android, wifi, wifimanager

I've found some strange behavior in Android WiFi API.
I need to get remote IP after WiFi connection has established to connect to a socket on the router. But to my regret I get some undefined behavior.

Suppose I have 3 Access Points within reach:

- NET1
- NET2
- NET3

Currently I connected to NET1 and I want to switch to NET3.

Here I connect to wifi:

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiConfig.SSID = "NET3";
...
int netId = m_manager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();                
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
m_context.registerReceiver(mWifiConnectReceiver, intentFilter);
m_manager.disconnect();
m_manager.enableNetwork(networkID, true);
```

m_manager here is `WifiManager`.

To receive WiFi event I have the following code:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mWifiConnectReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
    NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            Log.i("MyApp","--------------------------");
            Log.i("MyApp", info.getDetailedState() + ", " + info.getExtraInfo());            
            String ssid = m_manager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID();
            ssid = ssid.replaceAll("^\"(.*)\"$", "$1");
            Log.i("MyApp","SSID: " + ssid);
    }
});
```

After connecting the output is as following:

```
05-21 11:36:02.081 : CONNECTED, "NET1"
05-21 11:36:02.094 : SSID: NET3
05-21 11:36:02.095 : --------------------------
05-21 11:36:02.095 : CONNECTED, <unknown ssid>
05-21 11:36:02.098 : SSID: NET3
05-21 11:36:02.098 : --------------------------
05-21 11:36:02.098 : DISCONNECTED, <unknown ssid>
05-21 11:36:02.100 : SSID: NET3
05-21 11:36:02.100 : --------------------------
05-21 11:36:02.100 : DISCONNECTED, <unknown ssid>
05-21 11:36:02.104 : SSID: NET3
05-21 11:36:02.104 : --------------------------
05-21 11:36:02.104 : DISCONNECTED, <unknown ssid>
05-21 11:36:02.105 : SSID: NET3
05-21 11:36:02.107 : --------------------------
05-21 11:36:02.107 : DISCONNECTED, "NET1"
05-21 11:36:02.112 : SSID: NET3
05-21 11:36:02.112 : --------------------------
05-21 11:36:02.112 : CONNECTING, "NET1"
05-21 11:36:02.115 : SSID: NET3
05-21 11:36:02.240 : --------------------------
05-21 11:36:02.240 : CONNECTING, "NET3"
05-21 11:36:02.244 : SSID: NET3
05-21 11:36:02.245 : --------------------------
05-21 11:36:02.245 : CONNECTING, "NET3"
05-21 11:36:02.248 : SSID: NET3
05-21 11:36:02.308 : --------------------------
05-21 11:36:02.308 : OBTAINING_IPADDR, "NET3"
05-21 11:36:02.311 : SSID: NET3
05-21 11:36:07.885 : --------------------------
05-21 11:36:07.885 : CONNECTED, "NET3"
05-21 11:36:07.887 : SSID: NET3
05-21 11:36:07.903 : --------------------------
05-21 11:36:07.903 : CONNECTED, "NET3"
05-21 11:36:07.906 : SSID: NET3
```

And here I see lots of inconsistency:

- The first CONNECTED is puzzling - Why it's here? NET1 has already connected. Why when I connect to NET3 it fires CONNECTED for NET1?
- Why `NetworkInfo` reports NET1(and that's right) and getConnectionInfo() reports NET3??
- And the question that worries me most of all - how can I detect connection to proposed network in some clearly way? Is that possible to extract SSID from `NetworkInfo`?

**Updated**

I've found that the following code returns right SSID:

```
WifiInfo wifiInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO);
if(wifiInfo != null) {
    String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
    ssid = ssid.replaceAll("^\"(.*)\"$", "$1");
}
```

May be that could be user instead of `m_manager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID()`.